# Pass a variable into a stored procedures SELECT command

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a web page with a link to a stored procedure and I want to pass a variable to the stored procedures select statement.  The code so far is -

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[RTO]

@Weeknumber int,
@asset nvarchar(50)
AS

Begin 

SELECT @asset
FROM RTO_weeklyanalysis
Where weekNumber = @weeknumber

END
```

basically the @asset will be the name of the column but this will change depending on what the user selects on the page.

Comment: What language etc. are you using for your web page code? Do you have any server-side code so far you can show us to show where you're at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use Dynamic sql for this. Also use QuoteName() function when concatenating object names to your sql query. and use system stored procedure `sp_executesql` to execute the dynamic query the most safe and secure way of executing dynamic sql. Something as follows :

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[RTO]
@Weeknumber int,
@asset sysname
AS
Begin 
 SET NOCOUNT ON;
  DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @Sql = N' SELECT  '+  QUOTENAME(@asset) + '
              FROM RTO_weeklyanalysis
              Where weekNumber = @weeknumber'

EXECUTE sp_executesql @Sql
                     ,N'@Weeknumber int'
                     ,@Weeknumber
END
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a column name dynamicly in this way. The simplest way to achiewe what you want will be to exec whole query from temporary variable, i mean:

```
declare @query
set @query = 'SELECT ' + @asset  ' FROM RTO_weeklyanalysis Where weekNumber = @weeknumber'
exec sp_executesql @query
```